# React-native run-ios commands fails

Tags: ios, react-native

/Users/tnex-mac6/Desktop/React Native Projects/ReactDemoNavigation/node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTUtils.m:255:6: note: 'RCTExecuteOnMainThread' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
void RCTExecuteOnMainThread(dispatch_block_t block, BOOL sync)
     ^

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/tnex-mac6/Desktop/React\ Native\ Projects/ReactDemoNavigation/ios/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTPlatform.o Base/RCTPlatform.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactDemoNavigation.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactDemoNavigation.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Answer (score -1):

Before you try an upgrade, the error states that the CFBundleIdentifier doesn't exist, did you sanity check that?

to upgrade your version of react-native do the following:
Open your terminal, go to your react-native project folder and do a 
`react-native upgrade`.

Most of the times this solves the problem.

Comment: I tried upgrading the package, but still gives the same error. I followed all the steps given in the documentation.

Comment: react-native upgrade does solve the problem.  In my case the project bringing the error is my own project i pulled from github repo the same day with all the up-to-date react_native , react and Xcode