# New react-native project can't run-ios: The following build commands failed: CompileC

Tags: react-native

I am just trying to spin up a new react-native app but no luck.

react-native init NewApp
cd NewApp
npm install
react-native run-ios

Then see the below error:

```
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/arc/Desktop/websites-dev/react-native/testing_rn/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTProfile.o Profiler/RCTProfile.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/testing_rn.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/testing_rn.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

Using:

```
npm 4.1.2
node v7.5.0
El Capitan 10.11.6
Xcode 8.2
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "testing_rn",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "15.4.2",
        "react-native": "0.42.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
        "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
        "jest": "19.0.2",
        "react-test-renderer": "15.4.2"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
    }
}
```

It seems like this may be related to the build via terminal but app may still work in xcode?

- [Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist have tried most solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727230/print-entry-cfbundleidentifier-does-not-exist-have-tried-most-solutions)

github issue from 25 days ago:

- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12737

Some related questions:

- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7308
- [React-native run-ios commands fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41677132/react-native-run-ios-commands-fails)

=========================================================

**UPDATE:**

For me, this seemed to have something to do with 0.42.0 and above. I can run a 0.41.2 project that I install with

```
react-native init --version 0.41.2 example412
cd example412
npm install
react-native run-ios
```

And boom. It works. But this gets errors:

```
react-native init example_latest
cd example_latest
npm install
react-native run-ios
```

then above errors are back. Same errors with init version at 0.42.0:

```
react-native init --version 0.42.0 example420
cd example420
npm install
react-native run-ios
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I guess I needed to update xcode. I thought I was on 8.3 but apparently not. I also needed to update osx to 10.12.4 prior to updating my xcode. Now I'm all good and running a react-native init app at 0.42.3